# Macbook Pro Hot when sleeping/closed lid

Tags: macbook-pro

My Macbook Pro is hot when I don't use it and it's sleeping, and cold when I use it and watch videos. Makes no sense.

I searched and discovered it could be a wake issue. I typed in a code in terminal to check what's happening and why it wakes up. It came up with multiple events happening every minute. I saw other people with the same problem and they had events happening every 30 min/ 1 hour.

here are some of the events:

```
2019-08-16 19:53:03.339969-0400 0x5f8b40   Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
2019-08-16 19:53:05.434133-0400 0x5f8aad   Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
2019-08-16 19:53:58.319377-0400 0x74       Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.ARPT (Maintenance)
2019-08-16 19:53:58.319380-0400 0x74       Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.ARPT (Maintenance)
2019-08-16 19:54:04.202136-0400 0x5f8f80   Default     0x0                  726    0    corespeechd: [com.apple.corespeech:Framework] -[CSHostDaemon _isWakeReasonVoiceTrigger] Wake reason: <private>
2019-08-16 19:54:04.202141-0400 0x5f8f80   Default     0x0                  726    0    corespeechd: [com.apple.corespeech:Framework] -[CSHostDaemon _getPowerAssertionIfWakenByVoiceTriggerNotFromS3Sleep] Wake reason is not VoiceTrigger or it wake from S0i
2019-08-16 19:54:04.534285-0400 0x5f9016   Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
2019-08-16 19:54:06.712600-0400 0x5f917b   Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
2019-08-16 19:54:59.600543-0400 0x74       Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.ARPT (Maintenance)
2019-08-16 19:54:59.600564-0400 0x74       Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.ARPT (Maintenance)
2019-08-16 19:55:05.437861-0400 0x5f945f   Default     0x0                  726    0    corespeechd: [com.apple.corespeech:Framework] -[CSHostDaemon _isWakeReasonVoiceTrigger] Wake reason: <private>
2019-08-16 19:55:05.437866-0400 0x5f945f   Default     0x0                  726    0    corespeechd: [com.apple.corespeech:Framework] -[CSHostDaemon _getPowerAssertionIfWakenByVoiceTriggerNotFromS3Sleep] Wake reason is not VoiceTrigger or it wake from S0i
2019-08-16 19:55:05.751095-0400 0x5f94ef   Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
2019-08-16 19:55:07.926097-0400 0x5f952c   Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
2019-08-16 19:56:00.801918-0400 0x74       Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.ARPT (Maintenance)
2019-08-16 19:56:00.801921-0400 0x74       Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.ARPT (Maintenance)
2019-08-16 19:56:06.769039-0400 0x5f992c   Default     0x0                  726    0    corespeechd: [com.apple.corespeech:Framework] -[CSHostDaemon _isWakeReasonVoiceTrigger] Wake reason: <private>
2019-08-16 19:56:06.769043-0400 0x5f992c   Default     0x0                  726    0    corespeechd: [com.apple.corespeech:Framework] -[CSHostDaemon _getPowerAssertionIfWakenByVoiceTriggerNotFromS3Sleep] Wake reason is not VoiceTrigger or it wake from S0i
2019-08-16 19:56:07.092872-0400 0x5f99bc   Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
2019-08-16 19:56:09.246919-0400 0x5f9b27   Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
2019-08-16 19:57:02.131328-0400 0x74       Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.ARPT (Maintenance)
```

Answer (score 3):

I recently started to experience exactly the same issue, with exactly the same log output.

I would put my MacBook to sleep at night, as I have always done since I started using Macs in 2012 but in the morning it would have zero battery remaining, even from a full charge. If I happened to touch the MacBook during the night, it was very warm, even though it should be sleeping.

What was confusing for me is that occasionally it wouldn't happen and I couldn't figure out what the pattern was.

Eventually today I realised that the log messages are related to WiFi (ARPT in EC.ARPT = airport) and it clicked that I had recently set up a new WiFi network.

I've just done a little experiment, with the 3 WiFi networks I have access to, each of which uses different hardware.

BT Hub 6 - No log messages, laptop is cool
Asus RTAC68U - No log messages, laptop is cool
Linksys EA6400 (the new and default network) - Log messages every minute, laptop is very warm

It seems the reason it didn't happen 100% of the time is because occasionally I would be connected to the BT Hub 6 or Asus router when I put the Mac to sleep.

I haven't had the time yet to determine exactly why this is happening. My hunch is that there is either some kind of compatibility issue between the Mac and the Linksys or it's somehow related to the Linksys network not having IPV6, whereas the other ones do.

It's been 8 months since you posted and I can't be sure that you still have the same issue or that it's got the exact same cause but hopefully even if not, this will help somebody.

Edited to add: Today I moved the Asus router to replace the Linksys and the problem now occurs with the Asus, whereas it didn't before. This tells me that the issue was not the Linksys router itself but rather the network it's connected to.

I wonder if perhaps macOS is trying to connect to a service which for some reason is not reachable from that network, causing it to retry every minute. I don't have the time to analyse network traffic right now (and there's no guarantee that it would be clear what is going on anyway due to HTTPS/TLS).